# How to subtrac a numpy array element-by-elemnt by another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two `numpy` arrays, with just the 3-dimensional coordinates of two molecules.

I need to implement the following equation, and I'm having problems in the  subtraction of each coordinate of one of the arrays by the second, and then square it.

[image]

I have tried the following, but since I'm still learning I feel that I am making some major mistake. The simple code I use is:

```
a = [math.sqrt(1/3*((i[:,0]-j[:,0])**2) + ((i[:,1] - j[:,1])**2) + ((i[:,2]-j[:,2])**2) for i, j in zip(coordenates_2, coordenates_1))]
```

Comment: try np.sqrt(np.mean((arr1 - arr2)  ** 2)))

Comment: `math.sqrt` only works with single values, not arrays.  `np.sqrt` is best when using whole arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's numpy you can easily do it using the following example:

```
import numpy as np
x1 = np.random.randn(3,3,3)
x2 = np.random.randn(3,3,3)

res = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power(x1-x2,2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for the mess I made formulating the question. I have some questions about your answer, can I use ```np.square``` insted of ``` np.power``` and for my case would´t It be ```np.sum``` instead of ```np.mean```. Finally I have used the following line, but I still cant get the exact results so perhaps Im making a mistake somewhere. ```np.sqrt((1/3)* np.sum(np.square(coordenadas_2-coordenadas_1)))```

Comment: @JoseGraciaRodriguez can you share your data and expected result? It might be a small detail that is missed. And you can use `square` and `sum` it won’t matter